# Child package cannot read param value from parent ssis package

Tags: ssis, package, parent-child, parent

I think I must be crazy !! i have a big problem in my ssis project .

i have more than 40 package one parent and 39 childs

i use configuration method to get variable values from parent to child packages and it work well .. but when i copy my ssis project

to the production server i face the following problem .. childs package didn't read the variables values from the parent package

i revised the configuration many times i can't find any missing !!

any help please ...

Thanks,

Comment: Are you getting any error message or simply those values not been propagating to child packages.

Comment: Which version are you using? 2008 or 2012

Comment: No error messages !
i use version 2008

Answer (score 0):

You have to look for few things while implementing parent- child packages.

1. Parent package variable configuration only work if you call the child package from the parent package. And beware of the order of events in a package when you're using Parent Package Variable Configuration.
2. Unable to read parent variable - In  the child package you have to write/type the name of the parent package variable name. Unlike the variable of the child package, you can't select it, because only at run-time the variable of the parent package is known by the child package.

You can pass values from parent to child by two ways -

1. [Store the value in a variable in the parent package and use a script task in the child package to copy it](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2010/12/passing-variables-from-parent-package.html).
2. [Using the package configuration](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/06/passing-variables-from-parent-package.html)

Sometimes it depends on which value you are passing from parent to child. For example, in case of  logging connection manager property value, [it won't work](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/dmauri/archive/2006/04/02/9489.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, child packages get param values from parent Pckg at runtime only .. the problem is that i store the connection string of my OLDEB COnnection as variable and i get it from parent package ... so at run-time there is no problem .. but if i want to open the child package to edit something i face an error because child package can't see parent variable values !
any help ?